# How to treat missing values in multiple format as NA while loading on R?

Tags: r

I have a data set of this form it has missing values in form of NULL, blank cells and !VALUE  , I have to load this data set on R and want to treat all kind of missing values as NA on R. Can na.string argument on read.csv or read.table can take multiple values ??

my set - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZMUi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,na.strings can take multiple values in read.csv/read.table .

```
 Ex:
  dsa <- read.table("C://Users/....../dsa.txt",sep=",",header=T)
   ID Name Date
1  1   AA  2011
2  2   BB  2012
3  3   CC  2013

  dsa <- read.table("C://Users/....../dsa.txt",sep=",",header=T,na.strings = c("AA","2"))
 ID   Name Date
1  1 <NA> 2011
2 NA  BB  2012
3  3  CC  2013
```